# Moduli of convergent isocrystals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over the finite field $\mathbb{F}$.  Fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  Presumably we can naturally define the moduli functor of rank $n$, convergent isocrystals (for some fixed coefficient field) on $X$.  Is it known if this functor is reasonable? For example is it representable? If not does it form a reasonable stack?

Comment: I would be pleasantly surprised if the fibered category were representable.  I seem to recall that in the complex setting, the groupoid of rank $n$ connections is not a reasonable stack.